Migrating from OAuth2RestTemplate in Spring Boot 3 - what are the alternatives?
Before migrating to Spring Boot 3, we used OAuth2RestTemplate in one of our services, which worked excellently, especially when the response from the external service was '401 invalid_token'. This implementation had a useful feature - OAuth2ErrorHandler, which, in the event of receiving 401 and 'invalid_token' in the body, automatically renewed the token and retried the request with the new token. Additionally, if the response did not contain any body, it analyzed 'www-authenticate' in the header and retried the request as well.
In Spring Boot 3, OAuth2RestTemplate is deprecated, and I can't find any equivalent. I am considering writing my own implementation of the retry mechanism for similar cases.
Is there an alternative to OAuth2RestTemplate with a similar mechanism in the handler?

Spring Boot 3 uses Spring Security 6.x release versions. In Spring Security 6.3 (GA) and earlier, you can use WebClient with an ExchangeFilterFunction for both servlet and reactive applications. In Spring Security 6.4 (currently available in pre-release with 6.4.0-M4), you can also use RestClient with OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor. This release will be generally available next month (November 2024).
There is not currently a direct replacement of the retry mechanism. However, access tokens that are known to be expired (or within the clock skew time window which is 60s by default) will be automatically refreshed. Retry logic is not usually required in this case.
By default, the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager automatically removes invalid OAuth2AuthorizedClient instances (for example, if refresh token becomes expired, revoked, etc.) on failure so the next request will trigger re-authorization. This is done through a RemoveAuthorizedClientOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler which you can read about in the reference.
If needed, you can add retry support through Spring Retry, as reported by one user here. Retry would probably only be useful for automatically triggering a re-authorization flow for the user without surfacing a 401 error. This could be surprising though, because returning a 401 allows the UI (for example, a javascript application) to display a message to the user prior to redirecting for re-authorization. If you are using grant types other than authorization_code, your mileage may vary but please feel free to open an issue if you feel something is missing.
In summary, the retry mechanism from the legacy OAuth library is not usually needed with the new OAuth2 support in Spring Security since access token refresh is handled automatically.

Is there anything in the backlog to add some auto-configuration for RestClient instances with the OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor? Something similar to what we have with the @FeignClient (which entered in maintenance mode) and to what I provide for WebClient & RestClient in this starter. Also, is it planned to include a ClientHttpRequestInterceptor to forward the access token in the security context of a resource server request?

Re: auto-configuration for RestClient - Not at this time. The difficulty is that auto-configuring interceptors does not always allow for full customization, which then requires additional customizer options which aren't as good an experience as simply publishing a bean; it also is not always wanted or expected by users and they then request a way to turn it off. Creating your own auto-configuration when needed is quite easy to do. Re: resource server - See #15820 and upvote if desired.

When you stack the interceptor bean instantiation, the RestClient bean instantiation, the configuration of this RestClient with the interceptor, and the call of the @HttpExchange factory to get an implementation bean, you end with much more grunt code than what @FeignClient requires. Configuring the authorization (either Basic or Bearer from a registration or a resource server security context) and proxy settings satisfied all my use cases so far.

Please consider the following pretty usual use cases (I write plenty of those): OAuth2 client C calls resource server R1 on behalf of resource owner U1. To answer R1 needs to collaborate with resource server R2. R2 takes his access control decision based on the resource owner at the origin of the request U1. So, U1 makes a REST call authorized with the Bearer it received with the request. R1 also needs to collaborate with resource server R3, but this time in its own name (use client credentials). Imagine it without and then with my starter linked above.

Part_1
@SteveRiesenberg many thanks for your reply.
I'm struggling to grasp the concept behind the implementation of the authorize method in the ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider class. My concern is that for the client_credentials grant type, a refresh token should not be included (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.4.3). Therefore, I don't understand why we check if the token is within a 60-second window of expiring, and then send a request to the authorization service to exchange the token ...?

Part_2 The implementation in the authorization service for this type of grant does not foresee a refresh token - it has been like this so far and I am not sure if anything has changed - which means we will receive the exact same token in response and we will keep receiving it until it expires.
@SteveRiesenberg, could you explain the idea behind the implementation of authorize in the ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider class, specifically based on the clock skew window?

@dan please open a new question and I will take a look.

My working implementation boils down to two things:

Set clockSkew to 0 s.

OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials(
                        clientCredentialsGrantBuilder -> clientCredentialsGrantBuilder.clockSkew(Duration.ZERO))
                .build();


Add retry mechanism in case of 401:

public class WebClientRetryHelper {

    public static Retry retryUnauthorized() {
        return Retry.fixedDelay(1, Duration.ofMillis(500))
                .filter(throwable -> {
                    if (throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException ex) {
                        return ex.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
    }
}


@SteveRiesenberg do you think this is a good direction?

I don't have enough information to answer that. The fact that you need to change clock skew to 0s means there's like an issue on the authorization server side, or some misunderstanding or misconfiguration somewhere else and it's hard to know where. Changing clock skew to 0 should not be required.

@SteveRiesenberg thx,
I changed the clock skew to 0 because if a client is already authorized and the token has expired (is within the time window of the skew clock, which defaults to 60s), a request (clientCredentialsGrantRequest) will be sent to renew the expired token, which is the same as obtaining a new access token. The problem is that our implementation on the authorization server will not renew the token but will keep returning it until it actually expires. Can you provide me with an example of the correct configuration for the authorization server, please?

I think it might be important info that we have different versions of Spring Boot in the client (3.3.4) and the authorization server (2.7.15).

"The problem is that our implementation on the authorization server will not renew the token but will keep returning it until it actually expires." You seem to have customized the authorization server to do this. Why do you need to return the same token until it actually expires? "Can you provide me with an example" Please see the samples and reference documentation.

"I think it might be important info that we have different versions of Spring Boot in the client (3.3.4) and the authorization server (2.7.15)." I don't think this is particularly relevant in this case.
